# Better way to implement flipbook-style animation?

Tags: android

I'm using a `handler` to simply post at delayed intervals, cycle through an array of drawable resources and set the `imageResource` accordingly. It works just fine, but the "animation" is not super smooth. Is there some other way to implement this type of animation, where I just flip through images like a flipbook?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want is called a "Frame Animation" in Android.  The images and the time to display each on screen is defined in an XML file.  See the link below for details:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/animation-resource.html#Frame

Here is how I have it running in a quick test app I wrote:

```
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    ImageView rocketImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    rocketImage.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.jena);
    rocketAnimation = (AnimationDrawable) rocketImage.getBackground();
```

Then, inside of my drawable folder I have jena.xml:

```
    <animation-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:oneshot="false">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/jenaveve0000" android:duration="500"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/jenaveve0001" android:duration="500"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/jenaveve0002" android:duration="500"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/jenaveve0003" android:duration="500"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/jenaveve0004" android:duration="500"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/jenaveve0005" android:duration="500"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/jenaveve0006" android:duration="500"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/jenaveve0007" android:duration="500"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/jenaveve0008" android:duration="500"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/jenaveve0031" android:duration="500"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/jenaveve0032" android:duration="500"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/jenaveve0033" android:duration="500"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/jenaveve0034" android:duration="500"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/jenaveve0035" android:duration="500"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/jenaveve0036" android:duration="500"/>
</animation-list>
```

To start the animation I have:

```
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
    rocketAnimation.start();
```

Comment: That's definitely it, though for some reason it refuses to work. I've done it programmatically, like animationDrawable.addFrame... and then called start(), but it only shows the first frame. I'm fine with my using my Handler. (AnimationDrawable itself is probably just using a Handler itself, though I haven't looked @ the source that closely)

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look as below:
http://code.google.com/p/android-page-curl/

I think this page curl effect is great.

Comment: thanks outman. Flipbook was probably a misleading term. I don't need the pageflip effect. I'm just setting images one after another to give the effect of a moving animation. Each image is just slightly different... you know what I mean. Just wondering if there's some optimizations or a different approach to making this smoother.

Comment: I got what you mean. May a bitmap or drawable cache help you? just like WeakHashMap<Uri, Drawable> mCache = new WeakHashMap<Uri, Drawable>(); start a background thread to maintain the cache and load image from cache.